# Not able to format output as CSV

Tags: powershell, export-to-csv

Am not able to convert PS output to CSV format using `echo` function. I need to collect hardware information about multiple servers and got this script from internet. I modified it to collect only the necessary information such as Computername,HDD space, CPU details and RAM.

Below is my code:

```
$ArrComputers = "PC17"
Clear-Host
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) {
    $computerSystemRam = Get-WmiObject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer |
                         select @{n="Ram";e={[math]::Round($_.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB,2)}} |
                         FT -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize
    $computerCPU = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer |
                   select Name |
                   FT -HideTableHeaders
    $computerCPUCores = Get-WmiObject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer |
                        select NumberOfLogicalProcessors |
                        FT -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize 
    $computerC = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'C:'" -ComputerName $Computer |
                 select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}} |
                 FT -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize 
    $computerD = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'D:'" -ComputerName $Computer |
                 select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}} |
                 FT -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize 
    $computerE = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'E:'" -ComputerName $Computer |
                 select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}} |
                 FT -HideTableHeaders -AutoSize 
    echo $computer,$computerC,$computerD,$computerE,$computerSystemRam,$computerCPU,$computerCPUCores
}
```

and my output is coming as

```
PC17
99.9
12
537.11
15.98
Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz
12
```

What I need is to get this outputs as a comma separated value like below

```
PC17,99.9,12,537.11,15.98,Intel(R) Xeon(R) CPU E5-2630 0 @ 2.30GHz,12
```

so that I can open it in Excel. Please let me know what the problem here is? Or any other alternative solution to so as to get the output as .csv.

Comment: No echo is needed. Simply use "$computer,$computerC,$computerD,$computerE,$computerSystemRam,$computerCPU,$computerCPUCores"

Comment: Do not use FT ([`Format-Table`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/format-table?view=powershell-6)) either if you want to convert it to a `.csv` file.

Comment: At the end (after the `ForEach`) use [`ConvertTo-Csv`](https://learn.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.utility/convertto-csv?view=powershell-6)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Remove the `Format-Table`, use `ExpandProperty` and choose the right property from the array,

Also, I used `-f` to format the csv, see the differences:

```
foreach ($Computer in $ArrComputers) 
{
    $computerSystemRam = get-wmiobject Win32_ComputerSystem -Computer $Computer | select @{n="Ram";e={[math]::Round($_.TotalPhysicalMemory/1GB,2)}}
    $computerCPU = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer | select -ExpandProperty Name
    $computerCPUCores = get-wmiobject Win32_Processor -Computer $Computer | select -ExpandProperty NumberOfLogicalProcessors
    $computerC = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'C:'" -ComputerName $Computer | select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}
    $computerD = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'D:'" -ComputerName $Computer | select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}
    $computerE = Get-WmiObject -Class Win32_LogicalDisk -Filter "DeviceID= 'E:'" -ComputerName $Computer | select @{n="Size";e={[math]::Round($_.Size/1GB,2)}}
    "{0},{1},{2},{3},{4},{5},{6}" -f $computer,$computerC.Size,$computerD.Size,$computerE.Size,$computerSystemRam.Ram,$computerCPU,$computerCPUCores
}
```

Comment: This works !! , but when I give one more computername in the loop, only the 1st one is being read.

Comment: fixed, try now... removed the `return`

Comment: Yes, That works now !!